# Advanced filtering with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code below.

```vb
Sub step_9()
    Worksheets("sap_input").Activate
    Range("tbl_sap_input[#All]").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, _
        CriteriaRange:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("ex_types").Range("B25:B" & Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row), Unique:=False
End Sub
```

So, once I change `.Range("B25:B" & Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)`  to `.Range("B25:B37")`, everything works fine.

Can you please advise, how to fix?

Comment: I think it is coming from the unqualified range reference in `End(xlUp)` part which should be : `ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("ex_types").Range("B25:B" & ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("ex_types").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)`.

Comment: First thing that would come to mind is that `Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)` is an implicit reference to the `ActiveSheet`, which at that time is `Worksheets("sap_input")`. You probably want to work with explicit sheet references, even better would be to use variables (and avoid things like `.Activate`)